# Is it possible to customize violation constraint error renderingin symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, bootstrap-4, twig

I'm a beginner in symfony and I would like to create a registration form from scratch with the framework tools. So without using the "make:register ..." command line.

I've implemented a form and constraints with annotation syntax. However when I want to display the message error, it renders that :
[example of register form errors view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ZVL.png)

What I want is get all the constraint errors in my controller and render them in a bootstrap danger alert. Despite looking in the documentation, I cannot solve my problem. Hence, could you give a some explanations please ? Here is my code :

Entity :

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class Users implements  UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^(0|(\+)33)([1-9])([0-9]){8}$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Enter a valid phone number, please !"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@?!$£€*]){8,}$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Your password should contains a minimum of 8 characters with lower and upper case letters, numbers, and special symbols like @?!$£€*"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(name="account_verified", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $accountVerified = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_method", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $paymentMethod;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $paymentDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * Users constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfilePicture()
    {
        return $this->profilePicture;
    }

    public function setProfilePicture($profilePicture): self
    {
        $this->profilePicture = $profilePicture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountVerified(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->accountVerified;
    }

    public function setAccountVerified(bool $accountVerified): self
    {
        $this->accountVerified = $accountVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentMethod(): ?string
    {
        return $this->paymentMethod;
    }

    public function setPaymentMethod(string $paymentMethod): self
    {
        $this->paymentMethod = $paymentMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->paymentDate;
    }

    public function setPaymentDate(?\DateTimeInterface $paymentDate): self
    {
        $this->paymentDate = $paymentDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function setCreationDate(\DateTimeInterface $creationDate): self
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getUsername() method.
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;


    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/signup", name="User/signup.html.twig")
     * @param Request $r
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $p
     * @return Response
     */
    public function signUp(Request $r, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $p): Response
    {
        $user = new Users();
        $form = $this->createForm(UsersRegistrationType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($r);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $p->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('User/signup.html.twig', ["form" => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

View :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Création d'un nouveau compte Avanza{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form,  {'attr': {
        'style': 'width: 30%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
        border-color: #307424;'}}) }}
    <h4 class="text-center">Créer un compte</h4>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                {{ form_row(form.phone) }}

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                {{ form_row(form.password) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="width: 40%;">Valider</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Regard

YT

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change how form errors are displayed you will probably need to create your own form theme that extends your current theme (likely one of the bootstrap themes).

You are using `{{ form_row() }}` which will also render a [form_label-block](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L254-L260), which includes rendering a [form_errors-block](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L333-L345).

You probably want to overwrite `{% block form_label %}` so that it will no longer render the errors and then you overwrite `{% block form_errors %}` to render an alert instead. You can then manually use `{{ form_errors(form) }}` in your form where you want to show the alerts.

The form_errors-block could for example look something like this:

```
{% block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        {%- for error in errors -%}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ 'Error'|trans({}, 'validators') }}</strong>
                {{ error.message }}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_errors %}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer, I'll try it and come back to you if I need more explanations